# Can't show javascript variable in html

Tags: javascript, html

This is the code:

```
<div id="screen1">You do not have javascript enabled.</div>
<div id="screen2">You do not have javascript enabled.</div>
<script>
   document.getElementById("screen1").innerHTML = return window.screen.availHeight;
   document.getElementById("screen2").innerHTML = return window.screen.availWidth;
</script>
```

The output for both `screen1` and `screen2` is `You do not have javascript enabled.`, I thought this way would work because I used this before and it worked:

```
<div id="locale">You do not have javascript enabled.</div>
<script>document.getElementById("locale").innerHTML = getLang();</script>
```

Comment: remove the `return` from the `return window.screen.availHeight` portion

Answer (score 2):

If you remove the `return` keyword, everything will work as normal. Since you're not defining/inside of a function, the `return` keyword is out of place.

```js
document.getElementById("screen1").innerHTML = window.screen.availHeight;
document.getElementById("screen2").innerHTML = window.screen.availWidth;
```

```html
<div id="screen1">You do not have javascript enabled.</div>
<div id="screen2">You do not have javascript enabled.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.getElementById("screen1").innerHTML = window.screen.availHeight;
document.getElementById("screen2").innerHTML = window.screen.availWidth;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>My HTML</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<div id="screen1">You do not have javascript enabled.</div>
<div id="screen2">You do not have javascript enabled.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Try this without `return`

```
document.getElementById("screen1").innerHTML = window.screen.availHeight;
document.getElementById("screen2").innerHTML = window.screen.availWidth;
```

Output from my pc

```
<div id="screen1">860</div>
<div id="screen2">1440</div>
```